# Creating CSS effects in anchor tag

Tags: css

I have div box which is inside anchor tag.

Want to create some effect on the text inside div.

I coded but it does not show effect.
I wanted that when user take mouse over url in  then background should change to Yellow color:

```
.fragment h4: hover {
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

**Also the button here does not give on hover effect. Can someone let me know which effect is there in CodePan.com**

I want to keep my color and trying to create gradient and hover effect as it is on Codepan.com buttons

http://www.codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/riklv

**UPDaTE**

I want to keep box single clickable. And want to change url when it is mouse overed.

Comment: sounds like it needs JavaScript not CSS

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn Oh dear no, if there's no need to use javascript, stick to CSS.

Comment: he actually wanted to change URL when hovering

Comment: When hovering over the url (from what I understood)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in your code, `h4:hover` MUST go together:

```
.fragment h4:hover {
background-color:yellow;
}
```

*Please note how I removed the space between **h4:** and **hover***

The problem you're having with your button is that your CSS is incorrect, you forgot to add a `.` before the name of the class, i.e : `.button`. I just updated the jsfiddle to add this as well.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Waclock/U8gyf/1/)'s a working jsfiddle.

Comment: thanks buddy. can you please take look over button issue? Your answer is almost correct for me

Comment: thanks a ton. Dude I want to create button effect and look as it's in codepan.com login button. In sort attractive nice look. http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/U8gyf/2/ I tried again but dont know which parameter make required effect

Comment: Your answer I selected but appreciate if you can edit button for better look. I perform try and error.

Comment: If you want a better look try changing the gradient colors, what error did you get when you tried to change it?

Comment: there's no error. But changing gradient color does not give real effect. May I need to test it more

Comment: Yes, just keep changing the gradient or the background color until you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.fragment:hover h4 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This will change the color of the url if you hover over the big div (.fragment).